# Finding content between two words withou RegEx, BeautifulSoup, lXml ... etc

Tags: python, screen-scraping, fetch

How to find out the content between two words or two sets of random characters?

The scraped page is not guaranteed to be Html only and the important data can be inside a javascript block. So, I can't remove the JavaScript.

consider this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>StartYYYY "Extract HTML", ENDYYYY

</body>

Some Java Scripts code STARTXXXX "Extract JS Code" ENDXXXX.

</html>
```

So as you see the html markup may not be complete. I can fetch the page, and then without worrying about anything, I want to find the content called "Extract the name" and "Extract the data here in a JavaScript".

What I am looking for is in python:

Like this:

```
data = FindBetweenText(UniqueTextBeforeContent, UniqueTextAfterContent, page)
```

Where page is downloaded and data would have the text I am looking for. I rather stay away from regEx as some of the cases can be too complex for RegEx.

Comment: and what are `UniqueTextBeforeContent, UniqueTextAfterContent` in your example?

Comment: "as some of the cases can be too complex for RegEx."

How come? You have the unique texts before or after. That's not particularily complex, and dead easy to do in regexps.

Comment: but if he has unique markers why trouble regex?

Comment: True. regexps are not unable to handle it, but they are overkill. :)

Comment: @Lennart, I disagree -- this IS a case best handled by regex (and I'm definitely not a regex fanboy, mind;-). Still, if the OP doesn't want to hear about the best solution to his problem due to mistaken beliefs about "cases can be too complex for RegEx" (which is absolutely impossible if one trusts his specs), I'm not going to go courting downvotes -- fighting against the OP's mistaken beliefs isn't gonna gain me an accept, and once I hit the 200-points ceiling (early evening, usually;-) only an accept helps!-)

Comment: I didn't mean that RegEx couldn't do it. I find it not efficient enough! Too many passes. I might be wrong. I sometimes find 4 tags that are identical and each have a piece of data I want. One shows the date, the next shows the location ... etc. If I were to go for the tag, then I wouldn't know if I got the date or the location. What I am working on is I search to find the EndTag, then take the string upto the endTag, flip the string, then search for the StartTag, then remove the start tag and I have the text. For places where I have multiple identical tags I will search forward without filps.

Comment: Once I am done with the extractor, then it would be very simple to parse. Few of the examples provide in the answers below are good starts. I value your answers, however, Perhaps I don't find myself as bright as lot of people here, so, I am making an attempt to get my questions answered. Sometimes, I don't know enough to formulate even an intelligent question. :)

Comment: If you really have unique markers then the my answer will work, but I doubt that will be the case and then there is no option but to use regex and if you know the format of your input then may be libs like beautiful soup may work else you will have to write a neural network to intelligently identify what is to be extracted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt, this is tested.  While recursive, there should be no unnecessary string duplication, although a generator might be more optimal

```
def bracketed_find(s, start, end, startat=0):
    startloc=s.find(start, startat)
    if startloc==-1:
        return []
    endloc=s.find(end, startloc+len(start))
    if endloc == -1:
        return [s[startloc+len(start):]]
    return [s[startloc+len(start):endloc]] + bracketed_find(s, start, end, endloc+len(end))
```

and here is a generator version

```
def bracketed_find(s, start, end, startat=0):
    startloc=s.find(start, startat)
    if startloc==-1:
        return
    endloc=s.find(end, startloc+len(start))
    if endloc == -1:
        yield s[startloc+len(start):]
        return
    else:
        yield s[startloc+len(start):endloc]

    for found in bracketed_find(s, start, end, endloc+len(end)):
        yield found
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure your markers are unique, do something like this

```
s="""
<html>
<body>
<div>StartYYYY "Extract HTML", ENDYYYY

</body>

Some Java Scripts code STARTXXXX "Extract JS Code" ENDXXXX.

</html>
"""

def FindBetweenText(startMarker, endMarker, text):
    startPos = text.find(startMarker)
    if startPos < 0: return
    endPos = text.find(endMarker)
    if endPos < 0: return

    return text[startPos+len(startMarker):endPos]

print FindBetweenText('STARTXXXX', 'ENDXXXX', s)
```

Comment: text = "ppppYYYYyaddaXXXXblahYYYYqqqq"; FindBetweenText("XXXX", "YYYY", text) ... this produces '' but maybe the OP would prefer 'blah'

Comment: yes and there could be more complicated cases of marker embedded in marker, here I assume as OP said "unique markers"

Comment: can you extend your example to take the date out of this blob of text? """<div id=bold>California, US</div><div id=bold>June 12, 2009</div><div id=bold>Status: Active</div>""" Note that location, date and status are variables and can be different. Example """US</div>""" or """2009</div>""" cannot be used as end tags. Thx

Comment: you tell me the unique tags in the html and i will tell you the date

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what it would be in PHP.  No doubt there's a much sexier Pythonic way.

```
function FindBetweenText($before, $after, $text) {
    $before_pos = strpos($text, $before);
    if($before_pos === false)
        return null;
    $after_pos = strpos($text, $after);
    if($after_pos === false || $after_pos <= $before_pos)
        return null;
    return substr($text, $before_pos, $after_pos - $before_pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Slightly tested]

```
def bracketed_find_first(prefix, suffix, page, start=0):
    prefixpos = page.find(prefix, start)
    if prefixpos == -1: return None # NOT ""
    startpos = prefixpos + len(prefix)
    endpos = page.find(suffix, startpos) # DRY
    if endpos == -1: return None # NOT ""
    return page[startpos:endpos]
```

Note: the above returns only the first occurrence. Here is a generator which yields each occurrence.

```
def bracketed_finditer(prefix, suffix, page, start_at=0):
    while True:
        prefixpos = page.find(prefix, start_at)
        if prefixpos == -1: return # StopIteration
        startpos = prefixpos + len(prefix)
        endpos = page.find(suffix, startpos)
        if endpos == -1: return
        yield page[startpos:endpos]
        start_at = endpos + len(suffix)
```

Comment: I test the first version you have and works well on a single occurrence.

Comment: @VN44CA: I'm astonished that you accepted an answer that was not only later than mine but also recursive. Any particular reason?